# How can I set a bluetooth default controller

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I have ubuntu 18.04 and using 2 bluetooth sources. When I type `bluetoothctl` I get 2 bluetooth controllers but one of them (less desired) is set as default. How can I set other controller as default via terminal?

Answer (score 4):

using `list` command in bluetoothctl prompt will give you the list of controllers  with their mac id,  also showing which one is the default

> [bluetooth]# list
>
> Controller 14:16:91:15:F6:A0 david-acer #2 [default]
>
> Controller 14:D3:A7:56:F4:D0 david-acer #1

type `select` command with the mac id of the desired controller to use this controller as the default

> [bluetooth]# select 14:D3:A7:56:F4:D0
>
> Controller 14:D3:A7:56:F4:D0 david-acer #1 [default]

Comment: Be aware this only sets the default for this specific session of bluetoothctl, which can be a problem for scripted use.

Answer (score 1):

`bluetoothctl` has a default agent which is (at time of writing) the first enabled bluetooth device encountered when you run the application. There is no way to control this for future launches.

Within a single interactive session, you can use `select <bt addr>` to switch to a controller as default for that specific session of `bluetoothctl`.

For scripted use, you will have to issue that command first in standard input, using something like

```
echo -e "select aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\npair gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll" > bluetoothctl
```

to run multiple commands